# how can I improve my code to calculate distance between two locations in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

In my current `swift` app I have a code for calculating the distance between two locations. It works like this:

```
func calculateDisatnceBetweenTwoLocations(_ destination:CLLocation) -> Double{

let distanceMeters = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude).distance(from: destination)
let distanceKM = distanceMeters / amount

return distanceKM.roundedTwoDigit()
```

and the extension to `Double` looks like this:

```
extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func roundedTwoDigit() -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(2))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

now, no matter how long the distance is, it is always rounded to 2 digits.

I would like to change it, so that when the distance is higher than 4km, then it should show me it rounded to the base, so e.g. for 5.42 km it would show me 5, and for 6.78 it would show me 7. 
However if distance is lower than 4km, it should round it to the first digit, so e.g. for 3.21 it would show 3.2 and for 2.58 it would show 2.6.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: `pow(10.0, Double(2))` interesting way to write `100.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest two things:

1. Don't round the double, but format the result when converting to string for displaying
2. Don't make the formatting change at 4, it does not seem very intuitive

If you can live with these suggestions, you could use `NumberFormatter` to format to specific *number of significant digits*:

```
let nums = [0.12345, 1.56789, 2.49876, 5.99999, 9.49876, 11.55555, 19.54321, 123.6]

let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let f = NumberFormatter()
    f.maximumSignificantDigits = 2
    return f
} ()

nums.forEach {
    print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) ?? "n/a")
}

// Prints:
// 0.12
// 1.6
// 2.5
// 6
// 9.5
// 12
// 20
// 120
```

Comment: Using significant digits has its own problems. Especially the lose of precision for bigger values. I would consider a big problem to format `123` as `120`. You are right about the `4` limit. Ideally, such a random limit shouldn't exist. Also, it would be easier to switch to `meters` for smaller values. Technically the best solution would be to use `MKDistanceFormatter` that can actually switch to imperial system when needed.

Answer (score 4):

As always, you should use `NumberFormatter` to display numbers to the user, don't round numbers by yourself.

```
func formatDistance(_ distance: Double) -> String {
    let numDecimalDigits = (distance >= 4) ? 0 : 2

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = numDecimalDigits
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = numDecimalDigits

    let formattedDistance: String = formatter.string(for: distance)!
    return "\(formattedDistance) km"
}

print(formatDistance(6.78)) // 7 km
print(formatDistance(2.05)) // 2.05 km
```

Comment: your answer has some smallish issues, please refer to mine. If you want to fix yours, I am happy to delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is definitely the right way, Sulthan's answer is not totally complete:

if gives 2 decimal digits in cases of < 4 km and if it is rounded to x.0, it will print the trailing zero.

Furthermore 2.05 will will round to 2.0, not 2.1.

```
func formatDistance(_ distance: Double) -> String {
    let numDecimalDigits = (distance >= 4) ? 0 : 1

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = numDecimalDigits

    let formattedDistance: String = formatter.string(for: distance)!
    return "\(formattedDistance) km"
}

print(formatDistance(6.78)) // 7 km
print(formatDistance(2.05)) // 2.1 km
print(formatDistance(2.049)) // 2 km
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you wanted to do the operations in `Double`. Here is another variant:

```
extension Double {
    mutating func roundedTwoDigit() -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double((self >= 4) ? 0 : 1))

        if (self > 4) {
            self.round(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
        }

        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it seems to work, it gives your answer back as a Double as well

```
extension Double {
    func roundedTwoDigit() -> Double {
        if self < 4 {
            return (self * 10).rounded() / 10
        }
        else {
            return self.rounded()
        }
    }
}

print(Double(5.42).roundedTwoDigit())  //5.0
print(Double(6.78).roundedTwoDigit())  //7.0
print(Double(3.21).roundedTwoDigit())  //3.2
print(Double(2.58).roundedTwoDigit())  //2.6
```